# Sending data from component to view with this

Tags: angularjs

My problem is with 'this' 
I don't know how to call data from controller with 'this' i try ' ng-init="meProfileCtrl.getView()" ' and assign data in a way {{ user.name }}

```
'use strict';
function meProfileCtrl(DataService) {
    var self = this;
    this.getView = function () {
        DataService.allData().then(function (response) {
        self.user = response.data.me_view;
        console.log(user);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("error");
    });
}
};
angular.module('app').component('meprofile',{
        templateUrl :'templates/alldata.html',
        controller: meProfileCtrl,
        bindings: {
            getView: '=',
            user: '='
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the value of **controllerAs** which is`$ctrl` by the default, so if you didn't specify it you can use: `$ctrl.getView()`

But you can define it in your component, for example:

```
angular.module('app').component('meprofile',{
        templateUrl :'templates/alldata.html',
        controller: meProfileCtrl,
        controllerAs: myctrl,// <-- here
        bindings: {
            getView: '=',
            user: '='
        }
    }
);
```

and use: `myctrl.getView()` in your view

Component docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: Now i get "expression 'undefined' in attribute 'user' used with directive 'meprofile' is non-assignable!"

Comment: @Jacob.M it's not related in your topic now, https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign , you add user: '=' in binding but it's undefined

Comment: I found a solution self.$onInit = function()  instead of this.getView